# The API crashes when trying to retrieve multiple tags

Tags: bug, tags, api

Using [the `/tags/{tags}/info` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name), I try to retrieve the info for a few tags, but [the API crashes with](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/cx-oracle%3Bdjango-oracle%3Bjava-in-oracle%3Bnode-oracle%3Boracle%3Boracle-access-manager%3Boracle-adf%3Boracle-adf-mobile%3Boracle-agile-plm%3Boracle-analytics%3Boracle-apex%3Boracle-apex-5%3Boracle-apex-5.1%3Boracle-application-server%3Boracle-apps%3Boracle-aq%3Boracle-bam%3Boracle-bi%3Boracle-bpm-suite%3Boracle-cdc%3Boracle-client%3Boracle-cloud-infrastructure%3Boracle-coherence%3Boracle-commerce%3Boracle-commerce-cloud%3Boracle-cursor%3Boracle-data-integrator%3Boracle-data-modeler%3Boracle-ebs%3Boracle-enterprise-linux%3Boracle-enterprise-manager%3Boracle-export-dump%3Boracle-fdw%3Boracle-fusion-apps%3Boracle-fusion-middleware%3Boracle-golden-gate%3Boracle-home%3Boracle-http-server%3Boracle-jet%3Boracle-live-sql%3Boracle-maf%3Boracle-manageddataaccess%3Boracle-map-viewer%3Boracle-mds%3Boracle-net-services%3Boracle-nosql%3Boracle-objects%3Boracle-objects-ole%3Boracle-olap%3Boracle-opam%3Boracle-ords%3Boracle-osm%3Boracle-policy-automation%3Boracle-pro-c%3Boracle-rac%3Boracle-ras%3Boracle-rds%3Boracle-rdw%3Boracle-rules/info?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir):

> Server Error in '/' Application.

(click for larger view)
    [image: Error page]

**This is neither proper JSON, nor useful in any way to determine the problem.**

---

The `/tags/{tags}/info` route accepts a `pagesize` value of up to 100 and there is nothing to indicate that the number of tags passed to the `tags` parameter would be otherwise limited (nor should it be).

But **the API crashes if the length of the `tags` parameter exceeds 909 characters.**

Consider these API requests:

1. [cx-oracle;django-oracle;...oracle-rdw](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=cx-oracle%3Bdjango-oracle%3Bjava-in-oracle%3Bnode-oracle%3Boracle%3Boracle-access-manager%3Boracle-adf%3Boracle-adf-mobile%3Boracle-agile-plm%3Boracle-analytics%3Boracle-apex%3Boracle-apex-5%3Boracle-apex-5.1%3Boracle-application-server%3Boracle-apps%3Boracle-aq%3Boracle-bam%3Boracle-bi%3Boracle-bpm-suite%3Boracle-cdc%3Boracle-client%3Boracle-cloud-infrastructure%3Boracle-coherence%3Boracle-commerce%3Boracle-commerce-cloud%3Boracle-cursor%3Boracle-data-integrator%3Boracle-data-modeler%3Boracle-ebs%3Boracle-enterprise-linux%3Boracle-enterprise-manager%3Boracle-export-dump%3Boracle-fdw%3Boracle-fusion-apps%3Boracle-fusion-middleware%3Boracle-golden-gate%3Boracle-home%3Boracle-http-server%3Boracle-jet%3Boracle-live-sql%3Boracle-maf%3Boracle-manageddataaccess%3Boracle-map-viewer%3Boracle-mds%3Boracle-net-services%3Boracle-nosql%3Boracle-objects%3Boracle-objects-ole%3Boracle-olap%3Boracle-opam%3Boracle-ords%3Boracle-osm%3Boracle-policy-automation%3Boracle-pro-c%3Boracle-rac%3Boracle-ras%3Boracle-rds%3Boracle-rdw&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **works**
   Number of tags:             58
   Length of tags param:       908
   Len of encoded tags param:  1022
   Len of request URL:         1141
   ```
2. [cx-oracle;django-oracle;...oracle-rules](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=cx-oracle%3Bdjango-oracle%3Bjava-in-oracle%3Bnode-oracle%3Boracle%3Boracle-access-manager%3Boracle-adf%3Boracle-adf-mobile%3Boracle-agile-plm%3Boracle-analytics%3Boracle-apex%3Boracle-apex-5%3Boracle-apex-5.1%3Boracle-application-server%3Boracle-apps%3Boracle-aq%3Boracle-bam%3Boracle-bi%3Boracle-bpm-suite%3Boracle-cdc%3Boracle-client%3Boracle-cloud-infrastructure%3Boracle-coherence%3Boracle-commerce%3Boracle-commerce-cloud%3Boracle-cursor%3Boracle-data-integrator%3Boracle-data-modeler%3Boracle-ebs%3Boracle-enterprise-linux%3Boracle-enterprise-manager%3Boracle-export-dump%3Boracle-fdw%3Boracle-fusion-apps%3Boracle-fusion-middleware%3Boracle-golden-gate%3Boracle-home%3Boracle-http-server%3Boracle-jet%3Boracle-live-sql%3Boracle-maf%3Boracle-manageddataaccess%3Boracle-map-viewer%3Boracle-mds%3Boracle-net-services%3Boracle-nosql%3Boracle-objects%3Boracle-objects-ole%3Boracle-olap%3Boracle-opam%3Boracle-ords%3Boracle-osm%3Boracle-policy-automation%3Boracle-pro-c%3Boracle-rac%3Boracle-ras%3Boracle-rds%3Boracle-rdw%3Boracle-rules&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **FAILS**
   Number of tags:             59
   Length of tags param:       921
   Len of encoded tags param:  1037
   Len of request URL:         1156
   ```
3. [cx-oracle;django-oracle;...oracle-rules (no filter spec'd, so shorter URL)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=cx-oracle%3Bdjango-oracle%3Bjava-in-oracle%3Bnode-oracle%3Boracle%3Boracle-access-manager%3Boracle-adf%3Boracle-adf-mobile%3Boracle-agile-plm%3Boracle-analytics%3Boracle-apex%3Boracle-apex-5%3Boracle-apex-5.1%3Boracle-application-server%3Boracle-apps%3Boracle-aq%3Boracle-bam%3Boracle-bi%3Boracle-bpm-suite%3Boracle-cdc%3Boracle-client%3Boracle-cloud-infrastructure%3Boracle-coherence%3Boracle-commerce%3Boracle-commerce-cloud%3Boracle-cursor%3Boracle-data-integrator%3Boracle-data-modeler%3Boracle-ebs%3Boracle-enterprise-linux%3Boracle-enterprise-manager%3Boracle-export-dump%3Boracle-fdw%3Boracle-fusion-apps%3Boracle-fusion-middleware%3Boracle-golden-gate%3Boracle-home%3Boracle-http-server%3Boracle-jet%3Boracle-live-sql%3Boracle-maf%3Boracle-manageddataaccess%3Boracle-map-viewer%3Boracle-mds%3Boracle-net-services%3Boracle-nosql%3Boracle-objects%3Boracle-objects-ole%3Boracle-olap%3Boracle-opam%3Boracle-ords%3Boracle-osm%3Boracle-policy-automation%3Boracle-pro-c%3Boracle-rac%3Boracle-ras%3Boracle-rds%3Boracle-rdw%3Boracle-rules&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **FAILS**
   Number of tags:             59
   Length of tags param:       921
   Len of encoded tags param:  1037
   Len of request URL:         1133
   ```
4. [aws-java-sdk;clojure-java-interop;...javascript-events](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=aws-java-sdk%3Bclojure-java-interop%3Bcucumber-java%3Bdatastax-java-driver%3Bdrjava%3Beffective-java%3Belasticsearch-java-api%3Bewsjavaapi%3Bfacebook-javascript-sdk%3Bgoogle-api-java-client%3Bgoogle-oauth-java-client%3Bgrpc-java%3Bisomorphic-javascript%3Bjava%3Bjava-2d%3Bjava-3d%3Bjava-5%3Bjava-6%3Bjava-7%3Bjava-8%3Bjava-9%3Bjava-api%3Bjava-bytecode-asm%3Bjava-canvas%3Bjava-compiler-api%3Bjava-ee%3Bjava-ee-5%3Bjava-ee-6%3Bjava-ee-7%3Bjava-home%3Bjava-io%3Bjava-me%3Bjava-memory-model%3Bjava-metro-framework%3Bjava-module%3Bjava-security%3Bjava-server%3Bjava-service-wrapper%3Bjava-stored-procedures%3Bjava-stream%3Bjava-threads%3Bjava-time%3Bjava-web-start%3Bjava-websocket%3Bjava.nio.file%3Bjava.util.concurrent%3Bjava.util.date%3Bjava.util.logging%3Bjava.util.scanner%3Bjava1.4%3Bjavaagents%3Bjavabeans%3Bjavac%3Bjavacard%3Bjavacc%3Bjavacv%3Bjavadb%3Bjavadoc%3Bjavafx%3Bjavafx-2%3Bjavafx-3d%3Bjavafx-8%3Bjavafx-webengine%3Bjavafxports%3Bjavamail%3Bjavascript%3Bjavascript-debugger%3Bjavascript-engine%3Bjavascript-events&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **works**
   Number of tags:             69
   Length of tags param:       890
   Len of encoded tags param:  1026
   Len of request URL:         1145
   ```
5. [aws-java-sdk;clojure-java-interop;...javascript-framework](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=aws-java-sdk%3Bclojure-java-interop%3Bcucumber-java%3Bdatastax-java-driver%3Bdrjava%3Beffective-java%3Belasticsearch-java-api%3Bewsjavaapi%3Bfacebook-javascript-sdk%3Bgoogle-api-java-client%3Bgoogle-oauth-java-client%3Bgrpc-java%3Bisomorphic-javascript%3Bjava%3Bjava-2d%3Bjava-3d%3Bjava-5%3Bjava-6%3Bjava-7%3Bjava-8%3Bjava-9%3Bjava-api%3Bjava-bytecode-asm%3Bjava-canvas%3Bjava-compiler-api%3Bjava-ee%3Bjava-ee-5%3Bjava-ee-6%3Bjava-ee-7%3Bjava-home%3Bjava-io%3Bjava-me%3Bjava-memory-model%3Bjava-metro-framework%3Bjava-module%3Bjava-security%3Bjava-server%3Bjava-service-wrapper%3Bjava-stored-procedures%3Bjava-stream%3Bjava-threads%3Bjava-time%3Bjava-web-start%3Bjava-websocket%3Bjava.nio.file%3Bjava.util.concurrent%3Bjava.util.date%3Bjava.util.logging%3Bjava.util.scanner%3Bjava1.4%3Bjavaagents%3Bjavabeans%3Bjavac%3Bjavacard%3Bjavacc%3Bjavacv%3Bjavadb%3Bjavadoc%3Bjavafx%3Bjavafx-2%3Bjavafx-3d%3Bjavafx-8%3Bjavafx-webengine%3Bjavafxports%3Bjavamail%3Bjavascript%3Bjavascript-debugger%3Bjavascript-engine%3Bjavascript-events%3Bjavascript-framework&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **FAILS**
   Number of tags:             70
   Length of tags param:       911
   Len of encoded tags param:  1049
   Len of request URL:         1168
   ```
6. [aws-java-sdk;clojure-java-interop;...javascript-events;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=aws-java-sdk%3Bclojure-java-interop%3Bcucumber-java%3Bdatastax-java-driver%3Bdrjava%3Beffective-java%3Belasticsearch-java-api%3Bewsjavaapi%3Bfacebook-javascript-sdk%3Bgoogle-api-java-client%3Bgoogle-oauth-java-client%3Bgrpc-java%3Bisomorphic-javascript%3Bjava%3Bjava-2d%3Bjava-3d%3Bjava-5%3Bjava-6%3Bjava-7%3Bjava-8%3Bjava-9%3Bjava-api%3Bjava-bytecode-asm%3Bjava-canvas%3Bjava-compiler-api%3Bjava-ee%3Bjava-ee-5%3Bjava-ee-6%3Bjava-ee-7%3Bjava-home%3Bjava-io%3Bjava-me%3Bjava-memory-model%3Bjava-metro-framework%3Bjava-module%3Bjava-security%3Bjava-server%3Bjava-service-wrapper%3Bjava-stored-procedures%3Bjava-stream%3Bjava-threads%3Bjava-time%3Bjava-web-start%3Bjava-websocket%3Bjava.nio.file%3Bjava.util.concurrent%3Bjava.util.date%3Bjava.util.logging%3Bjava.util.scanner%3Bjava1.4%3Bjavaagents%3Bjavabeans%3Bjavac%3Bjavacard%3Bjavacc%3Bjavacv%3Bjavadb%3Bjavadoc%3Bjavafx%3Bjavafx-2%3Bjavafx-3d%3Bjavafx-8%3Bjavafx-webengine%3Bjavafxports%3Bjavamail%3Bjavascript%3Bjavascript-debugger%3Bjavascript-engine%3Bjavascript-events%3Ba%3Bb%3Bc%3Bd%3Be%3Bf%3Bg%3Bh%3Bi&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **works**
   Number of tags:             78
   Length of tags param:       908
   Len of encoded tags param:  1062
   Len of request URL:         1181
   ```
7. [aws-java-sdk;clojure-java-interop;...javascript-events;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&tags=aws-java-sdk%3Bclojure-java-interop%3Bcucumber-java%3Bdatastax-java-driver%3Bdrjava%3Beffective-java%3Belasticsearch-java-api%3Bewsjavaapi%3Bfacebook-javascript-sdk%3Bgoogle-api-java-client%3Bgoogle-oauth-java-client%3Bgrpc-java%3Bisomorphic-javascript%3Bjava%3Bjava-2d%3Bjava-3d%3Bjava-5%3Bjava-6%3Bjava-7%3Bjava-8%3Bjava-9%3Bjava-api%3Bjava-bytecode-asm%3Bjava-canvas%3Bjava-compiler-api%3Bjava-ee%3Bjava-ee-5%3Bjava-ee-6%3Bjava-ee-7%3Bjava-home%3Bjava-io%3Bjava-me%3Bjava-memory-model%3Bjava-metro-framework%3Bjava-module%3Bjava-security%3Bjava-server%3Bjava-service-wrapper%3Bjava-stored-procedures%3Bjava-stream%3Bjava-threads%3Bjava-time%3Bjava-web-start%3Bjava-websocket%3Bjava.nio.file%3Bjava.util.concurrent%3Bjava.util.date%3Bjava.util.logging%3Bjava.util.scanner%3Bjava1.4%3Bjavaagents%3Bjavabeans%3Bjavac%3Bjavacard%3Bjavacc%3Bjavacv%3Bjavadb%3Bjavadoc%3Bjavafx%3Bjavafx-2%3Bjavafx-3d%3Bjavafx-8%3Bjavafx-webengine%3Bjavafxports%3Bjavamail%3Bjavascript%3Bjavascript-debugger%3Bjavascript-engine%3Bjavascript-events%3Ba%3Bb%3Bc%3Bd%3Be%3Bf%3Bg%3Bh%3Bi%3Bj&filter=!bNKX0p1erS7Zir&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   ```
   Status:                     **FAILS**
   Number of tags:             79
   Length of tags param:       910
   Len of encoded tags param:  1066
   Len of request URL:         1185
   ```

Note that the `Len of request URL` is the length of the direct API call (URL encoded), Not the call via the livedocs page which is linked -- and a fair bit longer.